# 日本語に違和感: 「回答できる人を知っていますか? 」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

質問ページの下部に「回答できる人を知っていますか?」というのが表示されていますが、少し唐突なので、英語版の表記「Know someone who can answer?」と同じように、「誰か回答できる人を知っていますか？」と「誰か」を追加した方が良いと思います。
また「電子メール」は「メール」の方が自然です。
あと、最後の「?」が半角英数になっているので全角の「？」の方が望ましいです。
[image: 指摘用の画像]

Comment: 次回のビルド時に適用します。ありがとうございます。