# 日本語に違和感: 「電子メール」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

[日本語に違和感: 「回答できる人を知っていますか? 」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/72/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AB%E9%81%95%E5%92%8C%E6%84%9F-%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B%E4%BA%BA%E3%82%92%E7%9F%A5%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)
でも指摘されていますが、「電子メール」は「メール」の方が自然だと思います。

検索&置換してしまってよいと思いますが、思いつく箇所としては:

回答のついていない (?) 質問ページ

> 誰か回答できる人を知っていますか？ この質問を電子メール、Google+、Twitter、または Facebook で共有する。

投稿画面

> 投稿への新しい返信を電子メールで受信する

自分がした質問のページ

> 質問への新しい返信を電子メールで受信しますか?

自分のプロフィール

> 非公開:  電子メール

プロフィール編集

> 電子メール

基本設定画面に沢山あります。一部半角カナになっているので注意

> 未読の受信メッセージを電子ﾒｰﾙで受信する

Answer (score 2):

すべてのストリングをTransifexでコメントを追加しました：

https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40284625?comment=%2F149%2F

「メール」だけで通じないストリングもあるため、ちょっとずつ編集していきます。